# Question about contents of small bowel

Tags: diet

I know, or at least I think I do, that the contents of the stomach are called chyme and that it is acidic.  What are the contents of the small bowel called and is it acidic?

Answer (score 1):

I think its still called Chyme:

> After hours of mechanical and chemical digestion, food has been
>   reduced into chyme. As particles of food become small enough, they are
>   passed out of the stomach at regular intervals into the small
>   intestine, which stimulates the pancreas to release fluid containing a
>   high concentration of bicarbonate. This fluid neutralizes the gastric
>   juices, which can damage the lining of the intestine, resulting in
>   duodenal ulcer. Other secretions from the pancreas, gallbladder,
>   liver, and glands in the intestinal wall help in digestion.
>
> When food particles are sufficiently reduced in size and composition,
>   they are absorbed by the intestinal wall and transported to the
>   bloodstream. Some food material is passed from the small intestine to
>   the large intestine. In the large intestine, bacteria break down
>   proteins and starches in chyme that were not digested fully in the
>   small intestine.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chyme